# second project not showing tests in test explorer

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, test-explorer

I have a solution with a test project in it, based on nUnit.  All of the tests I created show in the test explorer window, I can execute, etc.

I added another unit test project to the solution, created references exactly like the first project, same nUnit version, same Platform target (Any CPU), same code structure, etc., just for a different product.  But I added tests (with Test attribute) to that project and they don't show in the Test Explorer.

All of my tests in the original project still show but no tests in my new project show.

How do I get tests from multiple projects to show in the Test Explorer window?
Is the Test Explorer window tied to a specific project?

Answer (score 0):

I spent a day trying to figure this out but once I posted the question, as luck would have it, I figured out the solution.  I changed the nUnit version back to 3.7.1.0 and it works - both projects now show tests in the Test Explorer window.

Comment: That fix sounds more like a side effect... something in the second project is probably failing under the newer version (what is it) of NUnit in a way that prevents discovery from finishing. Does the second project show up when it is the only project in the solution?

Comment: the newer version of nUnit was 3.9.  The second project did NOT show up (in Test Explorer) when it was the only project in the solution.